# Where are primary results (or effects) described?

Tags: discussion, election

I was away for a week and in some ways now return to the site as a new user. I see some implications that the primaries were over. Yet it looks like the 1,2,3 buttons are active for all candidates. Did a post with an announcement get buried in the pile?

Comment: if no one else does and you still care I'll let you know what happened at the end of the primary after the general election, I wouldn't want to influence  anyone's vote now.

Comment: @PeterTurner I don't think anything "happened" that isn't still public record. I've updated my answer with some clarifications, but the short version is that svidgen got eliminated. The voting activity of the primaries is still publicly available during the election, although this access will be reduced to only  those that made it to the election stage after the election is over.

Comment: Constructive criticism on how to make this a better question appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primaries are over. Now we are in the actual election voting phase.

First, let's clarify the *purpose* of the primaries. It seems a common point of confusion that voting in the primaries doesn't actually elect anybody. Primaries in general election terminology are for determining who the final candidates will be in the election. In the US, primaries determine who the running candidate is for a party. The actual election determines which candidate wins, but you only get to choose from the top voted members of each party as determined by the primaries.

In SE parlance, the primaries serve to whittle down the elections to the top ten candidates so that the final stage has no more than 10 names on the ballot.

In the case of this [C.SE's first election](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1), we had [11 candidates step up during the nomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination) phase, so we had to go to primaries to get it down to 10 before the final round of official voting. It was a lot of hoopla to eliminate just one nomination from the ballot, but that's the way math works.

The "outcome" of [our primaries](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary) as it were is that one candidate was eliminated, in [this case svidgen](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination#post-17598). The remaining ten have moved on to [the election phase](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election).

With primaries over, **now the ballot is finalized**. It remains to  cast an official vote. I say vote singular because each person has a voting power of 1, but [their vote is split](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2023/30) between 3 preference slots in such a way as to be most advantageous in electing their their first preference and so on. There are basically zero disadvantages to not choosing three preferences as the full weight of your vote will be used for the first choice if it will get them elected and only leftover unneeded/partial votes get transferred to your next preferences.

**This is the voting that counts.** Vote now to elect the future moderators of this site!